# Nginx high upstream_connect_time

Tags: nginx, docker, tomcat

I have a set up on Docker with Nginx being the reverse proxy for Tomcat services. On heavy load (testing) I am getting spikes in response time.

It turns out that one instance of Tomcat service without Nginx is working better than multiple services with Nginx in front of them, so the problem is between Nginx and Tomcats. Upon further inspection, I identified that the Nginx upstream_connect_time goes up to 3s, sometimes even 7s.

I tried playing around with keepalive, keepalive_connections, proxy_connect_timeout, worker_processes and worker_connections on Nginx but nothing helps. Next on my list is trying higher values for Tomcat max_connections.

What could be the reason for high upstream_connect_time?

Comment: Can you also share some information on the nginx.conf and the rate of requests encountering this issue?
Are there possibly some entries in the Nginx-logs?

Comment: Sorry, I solved this one by adding 
```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Without these, keepalive means nothing so my tyning of keepalive parameter had no effects.

Thanks for interest and sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this one by adding

```
proxy_http_version 1.1; 
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Without these, keepalive means nothing so my tyning of keepalive parameter had no effects.

If I understand correctly, http 1.1 enables using the same connection for simultaionus responses and requests and adding Connection "" in the header is used to keep the connection opened.

In Layman terms, previously I was saying to Nginx that it is allowed to use keepalives upstream, but I didn't configure it to know how to keep the connection opened (there comes the http 1.1 and header Connection part) so no keepalives where used.

In the end, with those two parameters set right, keepalive 500 was enough for "normal" performances but keepalive 1000 was kept to account for the high traffik situations.